# Does anyone know how to run 4-dimensional or larger problems using kde in the ks package in R

Tags: r, statistics, kernel-density

I am trying to get the kde for a four-dimensional dataset using the `kde` function in the *ks* package, but have not been successful. I am running the following code:

```
kde(m, h=delta, gridsize = n.grid)
```

where `m` is a `n x 4` matrix. I have n features in my dataset with 4 different variables. I have tried running this function with an `n x 3` matrix and the function works great, returning a 3 dimensional array kernel density estimate. When I run it with the four dimensional data matrix however it says I must supply the evaluation points (which is weird since the documentation says I only need to do that for d > 4).

So, I ended up creating a new evaluation point matrix that is n.grid x 4 in size with n.grid equally spaced points from the original data matrix m. However, when I run this, it returns to me a 1 dimensional array of estimates instead of a 4 dimensional array.

Does anyone know how to run kde properly for dimensions greater than 3?

Comment: Alternatively, does anyone know a better function/package for solve the kernel density estimate on 4-dimensional or higher data?

Comment: Omar, thank you so much for mentioning the `ks` package. I was looking for this functionality for the last couple of days. In turn I can offer you the `np` package and in particular the `np::npudens` function, maybe this helps you better.

Comment: @Beasterfield thanks for directing me to the `np` pacakge. It is exactly what I needed and seems to be working!